# best way to mix arrays with one same value php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have three arrays like this :

```
{ 0 => ["name"=>'name1' , "value1" =>'value1'] , ...}
```

and I want to mix these arrays if they have the same name!

this is what i want :

```
{ 0 => ["name"=>'name1' , "value1" =>'value1' , "value2" =>'value2' , "value3" =>'value2'] , ...}
```

what I have coded : (x, y , z are my arrays)

```
    $m = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($x); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($y); $j++) {
                if($x[$i]['symbol_name'] == $y[$j]['symbol_name']){
                $chartData[$m] = array_merge($x[$i],$y[$j]);
                $m++;    
                }
            }
        }
    
    $m = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($chartData); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($z); $j++) {
            if ($chartData[$i]['symbol_name'] == $z[$j]['symbol_name']) {
                $newChart[$m] = array_merge($chartData[$i], $z[$j]);
                $m++;
            }
        }
    }
```

but as you can see this might take too long (each array has more than 600 items), so can anyone help me find the fastest way to mix these arrays.

Comment: _mix these arrays if they have the same name_ that is unclear and your example arrays aren't clear.

Comment: Please share more details, like a full set of input and output data. From the given input, I don't see any way of getting to `value3`

Comment: I have 3 arrays with child arrays that have the same values and I want to mix these 3 arrays child into one array if they have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understand task:

```
$x = [
    ["name"=>'name1' , "value1" =>'value1'],
    ["name"=>'name2' , "value2" =>'value2'],
    ["name"=>'name3' , "value3" =>'value3'],
];

$y = [
    ["name"=>'name1' , "value11" =>'value11'],
    ["name"=>'name4' , "value4" =>'value4'],
];

$z = [
    ["name"=>'name2' , "value22" =>'value22'],
    ["name"=>'name3' , "value33" =>'value33'],
    ["name"=>'name5' , "value5" =>'value5'],
];


function mix_array(...$arrays) {
    $result = [];    
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $a) {
            if (!isset($result[$a['name']])) {
                $result[$a['name']] = [];
            }
            $result[$a['name']] = array_merge($result[$a['name']], $a);
        }
    }
    return array_values($result);
}   

print_r(mix_array($x, $y, $z));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [value1] => value1
            [value11] => value11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [value2] => value2
            [value22] => value22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => name3
            [value3] => value3
            [value33] => value33
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => name4
            [value4] => value4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => name5
            [value5] => value5
        )

)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it